# Labeling multiple incoming/outcoming groups of lines in feynmp?

Tags: brackets, feynmf, feynman, feynmp-auto

I'm trying to label multiple groups of incoming and outgoing lines using feynmp. I already managed to put brackets around the lines, but they aren't properly aligned. Is there a way to place the brackets on the same line, i.e. without the horizontal spacing between the brackets?

Thanks in advance!

This is my source code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[margin = 1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float,flafter}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\DeclareGraphicsRule{.1}{mps}{.1}{}

\newsavebox\feynbox
\newlength\tmplength
\parskip 2em
\newcommand\prefeynlabel[4]{%
  \setlength{\tmplength}{#2\ht#3}%
  \raisebox{#1\tmplength}{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\tmplength-.35\ht\strutbox}{#4}%
  \scaleto[1.7ex]{\raisebox{2.33pt}{\{}}{\tmplength}}%
}
\newcommand\postfeynlabel[4]{%
  \setlength{\tmplength}{#2\ht#3}%
  \raisebox{#1\tmplength}{%
  \scaleto[1.7ex]{\raisebox{2.33pt}{\}}}{\tmplength}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\tmplength-.35\ht\strutbox}{#4}}%
}


\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}
\vspace{.4cm}
{\bf {\Huge Subatomic Physics II}} \\
\vspace{.0cm} \\
{\bf Jake Vandevyvere}  \\
\hspace{\fill}  22/10/2015 


\noindent
\hrulefill

\section{Problem set 4}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\savebox\feynbox{%
\begin{fmffile}{one}
    \fmfframe(1,7)(1,7){
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,62)
        \fmfstraight{\fmfleft{l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9}}
        \fmfstraight{\fmfright{r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}}
        \fmfbottom{b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9}
        \fmflabel{$u$}{l9}
        \fmflabel{$u$}{r9}
        \fmf{fermion}{l9,r9}
        \fmflabel{$d$}{l8}
        \fmflabel{$d$}{r8}
        \fmf{fermion}{l8,r8}
        \fmflabel{$d$}{l7}
        \fmflabel{$\bar{d}$}{l3}
        \fmf{fermion}{l7,v1,l3}
        \fmflabel{$u$}{l1}
        \fmflabel{$u$}{r1}
        \fmf{fermion,label=$u$}{l1,v2,v3,r1}
        \fmf{gluon,label=$g$}{v1,v2}
        \fmflabel{$u$}{r7}
        \fmflabel{$\bar{u}$}{r3}
        \fmf{fermion}{r7,v4,r3}
        \fmf{gluon,label=$g$}{v3,v4}
        \fmfforce{0.2w,0.75h}{v1}
        \fmfforce{0.35w,0.75h}{v2}
        \fmfforce{0.65w,0.75h}{v3}
        \fmfforce{0.8w,0.75h}{v4}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    }
\end{fmffile}
}
\prefeynlabel{0.1}{0.3}{\feynbox}{$\pi^+$ }
\prefeynlabel{2.3}{0.3}{\feynbox}{$n$ }
\usebox{\feynbox}
\postfeynlabel{2.3}{0.3}{\feynbox}{ $p$}
\postfeynlabel{0.1}{0.3}{\feynbox}{ $\pi^0$}
\end{center}
\caption{$n\pi^+ \rightarrow \Delta^+(1232) \rightarrow p\pi^0$}
\label{Feynman 1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to guess what you want. If you replace your Feynman diagram code by

```
\begin{fmfgraph*}(110,62)
    \fmfstraight{\fmfleft{l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9}}
    \fmfstraight{\fmfright{r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}}
    \fmfbottom{b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9}
    \fmflabel{$u$}{l9}
    \fmflabel{$u$}{r9}
    \fmf{fermion}{l9,r9}
    \fmflabel{$d$}{l8}
    \fmflabel{$d$}{r8}
    \fmf{fermion}{l8,r8}
    \fmflabel{$d$}{l7}
    \fmflabel{$\bar{d}$}{l3}
    \fmf{fermion}{l7,v1,l3}
    \fmflabel{$u$}{l1}
    \fmflabel{$u$}{r1}
    \fmf{fermion,label=$u$}{l1,v2,v3,r1}
    \fmf{gluon,label=$g$}{v1,v2}
    \fmflabel{$u$}{r7}
    \fmflabel{$\bar{u}$}{r3}
    \fmf{fermion}{r3,v4,r7}
    \fmf{gluon,label=$g$}{v3,v4}
    \fmfforce{0.2w,0.75h}{v1}
    \fmfforce{0.35w,0.75h}{v2}
    \fmfforce{0.65w,0.75h}{v3}
    \fmfforce{0.8w,0.75h}{v4}
    \fmfv{label=$n\left\{\begin{array}{c}\\[2cm]\end{array}\right.$\\[3cm]}{l6}
    \fmfv{label=$\pi^+\left\{\begin{array}{c}\\[1.5cm]\end{array}\right.$\\[-3.3cm]}{l4}
    \fmfv{label=$\left.\begin{array}{c}\\[2cm]\end{array}\right\}p$\\[3cm]}{r6}
    \fmfv{label=$\left.\begin{array}{c}\\[1.5cm]\end{array}\right\}\pi^0$\\[-3.3cm]}{r4}
\end{fmfgraph*}
```

you obtain

[image]

Notice that I also reversed the arrow for the outgoing \bar u. This is, of course, not the most beautiful solution but I hope it gives you what you wanted.